# Multiple dynamic tables in npgsql / Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, npgsql

Currently trying to move away from pure npgsql to Entity Framework, however database itself is a bit weird.

There used to be a table `Values`. However, it got big very fast (thousands of new records every day), so instead now it creates a few (3 - 5) new tables every day and writes into them, each table called `Values_number`. There is currently about four thousand of them.

So what is the best way to work with those tables? I obviously cannot, as code generator suggests, create four thousand same classes, and I can't change the database either.

I'm not very experienced with EF, so detailed responses will be very appreciated!

**Edit**
Currently it works this way:
 1. Figure out table number we need. For example, 3433.
 2. Directly insert table name(`Values_3433`) into SELECT/INSERT/etc `query` string.
 3. Execute query:

```
dbTransaction = dbConnection.BeginTransaction();
        dbCommand.Transaction = dbTransaction;
        dbCommand.CommandText = query;
        dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        dbTransaction.Commit();
```

My question is, what is the EF way to do the same?

Comment: How is your software supposed to track those schema changes? AFAIK database is consistent object. Schema changes on insert isn't the way to go...

Comment: Its not supposed to track anything other than current table number which is always available from separate service. Edited my question.

Comment: If you only need to read and write to the current table, you can map it in OnModelCreating.  If you need to read and write to multiple, then you can integrate dynamic SQL with EF.